# How to get the 4-velocity of a fluid in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, spacetime, metric-tensor, velocity

If I know the energy-momentum tensor of a fluid, how to get the 4-velocity of this fluid in general relativity? Additionally, I find the 4-velocity of a fluid  determined by $u_a$ which satisfies $u_a u^a=-1$ in some books. But I don't know why the 4-velocity of a fluid determined by spacetimes rather than the energy-momentum tensor.

Comment: You just have to choose an unit time like vector field. There is no unique choice. And depending on your choice, the expression of density, pressure etc will change

Comment: @KP99 But in schwarzschild spacetime, we also can define a 4-velocity according to metric and there is no fluid.  What is difference between this 4-velocity and the 4-velocity of a fluid?

Comment: The 4-velocity of a fluid (in cosmology or ADM formalism) is timelike everywhere. It's not true for Schwarzschild, isn't it?

Comment: Landau vol 2 2nd ed chapter 89 shows at the end the (complicated) expressions, supposedly for time independent space time, not sure if the calculation fails for time dependent. The also show the fluid tensor in paragraph 97 for spherical symmetric metric (only in 2nd edition, and I am not sire if T10 is fully correct, there seems a factor of 1/2 in one of the exponentials whichwouldbt belong of the formula of par 89 is applicable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general relativity, the four velocity can be defined similar to how velocity is defined in Newtonian mechanics, except now we must keep in mind two things:

1. No specific choice of coordinate system is better than another
2. The 'time' against which we measure a rate of motion is itself a choice of coordinate.

Therefore we first come to a 'unique' choice of time or rather, something which can  be agreed upon by all observers.

In special relativity [my metric being $(-1, 1, 1, 1)$ ], the proper time is such an object defined by

$$d\tau^2 = - \frac{ds^2}{c^2} = dt^2 - \frac{d\vec{x}^2}{c^2}~.$$
Hence, if I choose coordinates $x^{\mu} = (t, \vec{x})$, then the four velocity $u^{\mu}$ is defined as:

$$u^{\mu} = \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau} = \gamma (1, \vec{v})$$

where $\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}$ is the usual spatial 3 velocity and $\gamma = (1 - v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$ is the Lorentz factor in special relativity. If we now compute $u^{\mu}u_{\mu}$, we obtain:

$$u^{\mu}u_{\mu} = \eta_{\mu \nu}u^{\mu}u^{\nu} = \gamma^2(-1 + \frac{v^2}{c^2}) = -1~.$$

Note that we are discussing the velocity of a timelike tracjectory and this normalisation of $u^{\mu}u_{\mu}= -1$ simply reiterates this timelike nature.

In general relativity this is further generalised where one can use any affine parameter. Simply put one can use any $\lambda = f(\tau)$ and take

$$u^{\mu} = \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}~,$$

such that the timelike nature is still retained since we can still take $u^{\mu}u_{\mu} = -1$. Different parameters correspond to different velocities and really, physically this means going between different frames. An analogy is to study the motion of a car either by standing on the road, or by travelling alongside the car with some non-zero relativity velocity or by sitting in the car with a co-moving velocity.

In the context of fluid mechanics the same applies. Different unit timelike vectors  simply correspond to different frames from which you study the fluid. As in the example of the car, the fluid quantities such as its energy density or pressure will change between such choices of velocity. In a spherically symmetric background with line element $ds^2 = -fdt^2 + g dr^2 + r^2~d\Omega^2$, a particularly simple choice of velocity is the co-moving velocity:

$$u^{\mu}_c = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}, 0,0,0)~.$$

This represents a frame where the observer is sitting on a fluid particle and travelling alongside the fluid. Again, note that $u_c^{\mu}u_{c~\mu} =  g_{\mu \nu}u^{\mu}_cu^{\nu}_c = -1$.

The energy momentum tensor of any object is simply a measure of the energy and the momentum of the object in a given frame. The fact that it is a tensor means that we know how these quantities transform when we move between frames. The velocity we use to study the fluid need not be the velocity of the fluid itself. Often, a lot of the interesting behaviour associated to the fluid (such as dissipation) is studied from an arbitrary frame whose velocity is taken to be a unit, timelike vector field.